# Can I overwrite the column type mapping for one single column

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-migration-assi

I am migrating an Oracle database to SQL Server. Through project settings I can change, for instance, type `number` to type `bigint`. This can also be done or overwritten at the table level.

But I need to overwrite at the column level. For one column I need `number` to `Int` type mapping. For another column I need `number` to be `decimal(10, 3)`. Other columns in the same table should follow the general project settings.

I cannot find how to do this, it looks like it can only be done at the whole table level.

Is it possible at the column level?

Using SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle v8.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Migration Assistant you can export the migration or table creation as script.
Alter the script in the Studio, execute it there and refresh the database in the Migration Assistant.
In the Migration Studio you migrate the data to the created tables.